# Return Form Values Within Text

Tags: forms

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
<form id="myForm" action="form_action.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Bob"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Smith"><br>
</form> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[1].value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

I like how this works, but can't figure out how to define where and how the values are displayed.  Ideally, I would like them to appear at specified places within a large block of text.

For example, with the values above, I could have the person put in their first name and last name, and then have the following show with the appropriate values in place:

[FirstName]'s last name is [LastName].

Right now, I can't figure out how to have the values they input show where I want them within other text.